# How to get sas date format "YYYYMM"

Tags: date, sas

How to get sas date format "YYYYMM" in SAS ?

From this code below I would get '2011-11-01'

```
call symput('me',"'"||put(intnx('month',today(),-1 ),yymmdd10.)||"'");
```

I'm trying to get something like :  '2011-11'

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro version:

```
%let date = %sysfunc(today());
%let me = %str(%")%sysfunc(intnx(month,&date,-1),yymmd7.)%str(%");

%put &me;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can replace yymmdd10. with yymmd7.
that should be the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydate = put(date, YYMMD7.)
```

See [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect011.htm) for details.

Answer (score -1):

For more information on formats visit http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002231336.htm

You can use one of the examples or "create" your own.

For example:

```
data datum;
datum=date();
datum1mback= INTNX( 'month', datum, -1); 
format datum1mback yymmn6.; /* returns 201111 (if we consider the date of the question of course) */
run; 

/* yymmp6. returns 11.11 */
/* yymmc8. returns 2011:11 */
/*...*/
```

Comment: This doesn't work as written. I'm using YM_pre365 = INTNX( 'DTMONTH', seg_dis_dt, -1);
format YM_pre365 yymmn6.; but it just gives me MISSING for the result.